# Using ERASE button as PIO on Due

Tags: arduino-due

I'm working on a demo program for which I want to use minimal resources: all I need is one LED and one pushbutton.

I'd very much like to use on-board resources. The user LED (PB27) is fine (I'd have liked one more, but there it is).

I read in the datasheet that the ERASE button can be used as an input (PC0) provided that I clear the SYSIO12 bit in the System I/O Configuration Register CCFG_SYSIO.

I find that if I do this I can push the ERASE button without erasing flash (!), but PC0 always reads as 0 (even if I enable pullup; ought to be already enabled, you'd think).

I should say that PC1 works just fine.

Has anyone else got ERASE => PC0 to work? is there documentation I've missed? (in ASF, some of the other boards in `sam/applications/getting_started/` disable the ERASE button, but not this one).